# MySQL: CASE outside JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, case

I have a table where I want to do different joins based on the value of a field in the source table. This is my current attempt:

```
SELECT i.name, c.name, loc.name FROM `item` i
CASE WHEN (i.loc_exception IS NOT NULL) THEN (
    JOIN `location_exceptions` le ON i.loc_exception = le.id
    JOIN `location` loc ON le.id_location = loc.id
    JOIN `city` c ON loc.`id_city` = c.id
) ELSE (
    JOIN `location` loc ON i.`id_location` = loc.id
    JOIN `city` c ON i.`id_city` = c.id
)
WHERE i.id = 5
```

Is it even possible to use CASE as I've attempted here? If not, is there any other way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: No its not possible this way. One thing you can do use `left join location_exceptions` but that depends on your dataset and desired result.

Comment: case is used to tweak with the output from the query and not the query dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Say I use left join – is it possible to use some kind of logic to decide which result to return? Like, if `loc_exception` has a value, select these two instead of those two.

Comment: Seems i can use CASE within the SELECT part of the query, so that works. Thanks again :)